# Writing a string in a multidimensional array at once C

Tags: c, string, multidimensional-array

Let's say I have a multidimensional array :

```
char myArray[3][15]={
"foofoofoo\0",
"barfoofoo\0",
"foobarfoo\0"};
```

Do I have to run a loop to set new strings in myArray, or is there any way to do this in C:

```
myArray[][]={
"secondChain\0",
"newChain\0",
"foofoofoo\0"};
```

I'm quite new to the magic world of code, so please excuse my question if it's dumb!

Comment: You don't need to add the terminator character `'\0'`, it's done automatically.

Comment: You can use strcpy function to set new strings to the myArray.

Comment: Here's a tutorial:  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_multi_dimensional_arrays.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got C99 with support for compound literals, you don't have to write the loop in your code (you can use a single call to `memset()` to do the job, which hides the loop inside the function):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char myArray[3][15] = {"foofoofoo", "barfoofoo", "foobarfoo"};

    printf("Before: %s %s %s\n", myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2]);
    memcpy(myArray, ((char[3][15]){"secondChain", "newChain", "foofoofoo"}), sizeof(myArray));
    printf("After:  %s %s %s\n", myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

---

The extra parentheses around the compound literal `((char[3][15]){"secondChain", "newChain", "foofoofoo"})` are necessary with the library I use (on Mac OS X 10.8.5 with GCC 4.8.1) because there's a macro definition for `memcpy()` and the commas in the compound literal confuse the C preprocessor if they are not enclosed in a set of parentheses:

```
mass.c: In function ‘main’:
mass.c:9:91: error: macro "memcpy" passed 5 arguments, but takes just 3
     memcpy(myArray, (char[3][15]){"secondChain", "newChain", "foofoofoo"}, sizeof(myArray));
```

Nominally, they are unnecessary.  If it was written:

```
(memcpy)(myArray, (char[3][15]){"secondChain", "newChain", "foofoofoo"}, sizeof(myArray));
```

it would be OK because that is not an invocation of the function-like `memcpy()` macro.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    char myArray[3][15]= {"foofoofoo", "barfoofoo", "foobarfoo"};

    //Set New values here
    strcpy(myArray[0], "Test1");
    strcpy(myArray[1], "Test2");
    strcpy(myArray[2], "Test3");

    printf("%s, %s, %s", myArray[0], myArray[1], myArray[2]);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Test1, Test2, Test3
```

Comment: Use strncpy so that there's no danger of running of the end of the arrays.

Comment: The trouble with `strncpy()` is that there's a danger that the arrays won't be null terminated if the string to be copied is too long.  It is a very odd function; if you say the array is 15 bytes long, it always writes 15 bytes (and if you say it's 20 KiB, it writes 20 KiB, even if the source string is only 5 characters long), using null padding if necessary, and not null terminating if the source string is overlong.  Be cautious — very cautious.

Comment: ISO/IEC 9899:2011: _§7.24.2.4 The `strncpy` function: The strncpy function copies not more than `n` characters (characters that follow a null character are not copied) from the array pointed to by `s2` to the array pointed to by `s1`.308) […] If the array pointed to by `s2` is a string that is shorter than `n` characters, null characters
are appended to the copy in the array pointed to by `s1`, until `n` characters in all have been
written._ and _308) Thus, if there is no null character in the first `n` characters of the array pointed to by `s2`, the result will
not be null-terminated._

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yes I know this. But before you edited your comment it was unclear to me what you meant by '_if you say the array is 15 bytes long, it always writes 15 bytes (and if you say it's 20 KiB, it writes 20 KiB, even if the source string is only 5 characters long)_'. Thought it was a typo because there is no `strncpy()` in this answer's code :)